# Sumar valores de un arreglo multidimensional en PHP (Framework laravel)

Tags: php

Tengo un arreglo que  contiene el peso de unos archivos y sus ids, deseo calcular el total de una columna del arreglo

En el código PHP inserto los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
//Se inicializa la variable
 $newArray=array(); //Nuevo arreglo bidimensional
//Dentro de un for se van insertando los datos
 $newArray[$i]['size'] = $totalSize;
 $newArray[$i]['idCloud'] = $id;
/*Dichos datos se encuentran en una iteración, cuyo código no es necesario de anexar para la compresión del problema.*/
```

En consola me imprime de ésta manera (lo devuelvo por medio de AJAX en un for con un console.log(data.sizeCloud[a]), mi problema se enfoca en PHP, hacer caso omiso de la estructura de la respuesta):

```
{size: 2.29, idCloud: 1}
{size: 18.42, idCloud: 5}
{size: 52.34, idCloud: 6}
```

Deseo obtener el total del peso de la columna de 'size' guardándola en una variable por medio de PHP, espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Lo que pasa es que devuelvo el resultado en AJAX (consola de JS) pero mi problema es no saber como sumar la columna del arreglo multidimensional por lado de PHP

Comment: Me gustaría realizar la operación directamente en el controlador, puedes aportar tu respuesta, te lo agradecería, pero optaría por ejecutarlo en el backend.

Comment: ¿Cómo debo implementar lo que me ofreciste en JS? en el lado de AJAX tengo lo siguiente en un for: console.log(data.sizeCloud[a]) y obtengo la estructura de mi pregunta, para acceder por ejemplo al size especifico con lo siguiente data.sizeCloud[a].size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según entiendo no queda otra que iterar el array, la suma podés hacerla acumulando con un for en php, o también con javascript cuando iteras para mostrar los registros aprovechas el ciclo y también acumulas los size para tener el total, cualquiera de las 2 formas.

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto mi problema como antes se menciona en una respuesta, iterándola en un foreach.

```
$sum=0;
 foreach($newArray as $num => $values) {
     $sum += $values[ 'size' ];
 }
//Se especifica solo la suma en la dimensión de 'size'
```

De esta forma he resuelto mi problema sumando todo los resultado de la dimensión de size.